# Testing firebase functions in vuejs

Tags: javascript, firebase, unit-testing, vue.js, jestjs

I want to unit test my vue components. Since I'm working with firebase this is a little bit difficult.

Fir of all, I created a `__mocks__` folder to contain all my mocked functions. Inside that folder, I've created `firebase.js`:

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase';

const onAuthStateChanged = jest.fn();

const getRedirectResult = jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve({
  user: {
    displayName: 'redirectResultTestDisplayName',
    email: 'redirectTest@test.com',
    emailVerified: true,
  },
}));

const sendEmailVerification = jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve('result of sendEmailVerification'));

const sendPasswordResetEmail = jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve());

const createUserWithEmailAndPassword = jest.fn(() => {
  console.log('heeeeelllo');
  Promise.resolve({
    user: {
      displayName: 'redirectResultTestDisplayName',
      email: 'redirectTest@test.com',
      emailVerified: true,
    },
  });
});

const signInWithEmailAndPassword = jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve('result of signInWithEmailAndPassword'));

const signInWithRedirect = jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve('result of signInWithRedirect'));

const initializeApp = jest // eslint-disable-line no-unused-vars
  .spyOn(firebase, 'initializeApp')
  .mockImplementation(() => ({
    auth: () => ({
      createUserWithEmailAndPassword,
      signInWithEmailAndPassword,
      currentUser: {
        sendEmailVerification,
      },
      signInWithRedirect,
    }),
  }));

jest.spyOn(firebase, 'auth').mockImplementation(() => ({
  onAuthStateChanged,
  currentUser: {
    displayName: 'testDisplayName',
    email: 'test@test.com',
    emailVerified: true,
  },
  getRedirectResult,
  sendPasswordResetEmail,
}));

firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider = jest.fn(() => {});
firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider = jest.fn(() => {});
```

This file, I took from: https://github.com/mrbenhowl/mocking-firebase-initializeApp-and-firebase-auth-using-jest

The component I want to test is called `EmailSignupLogin`. In this particular case, I want to test the `registerViaEmail`-method:

```
methods: {
    registerViaEmail() {
      if (this.password.length > 0 && this.password === this.passwordReenter) {
        firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.emailAdress, this.password).then((result) => {
          const { user } = result;
          console.log(result);
          this.setUser(user);
          this.$router.push('/stocks');
        }).catch((error) => {
          const errorCode = error.code;
          const errorMessage = error.message;
          this.error = errorMessage;
          console.error(errorCode, errorMessage);
        });
      } else {
        this.error = 'passwords not matching';
      }
    },
  },
```

Now to my test file(`email-signup-login.spec.js`):

```
import { mount } from '@vue/test-utils';
import Vue from 'vue';
import EmailSignupLogin from '@/components/email-signup-login';

jest.mock('../../__mocks__/firebase');

describe('EmailSignupLogin', () => {
  let wrapper;
  const mockFunction = jest.fn();

  beforeEach(() => {
    wrapper = mount(EmailSignupLogin, {
      data() {
        return {
          password: '123456',
          passwordReenter: '123456',
          emailAdress: 'test@test.com',
        };
      },
      store: {
        actions: {
          setUser: mockFunction,
        },
      },
    });
  });

  describe('methods', () => {
    describe('#registerViaEmail', () => {
      it('calls mockFunction', async () => {
        await wrapper.vm.registerViaEmail();

        expect(mockFunction).toHaveBeenCalled();
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Inside the `registerViaEmail`-method I call the `setUser`-action, which is a vuex-action.

The problem is that it doesn't seem to call my mocked functions from `__mocks__/firebase.js`. Can somebody please tell me why?

Comment: What error you're facing? If not, can you try to add the required function to the test file once and check, If that is wokring fine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several issues turned up in your code:

1. `registerViaEmail()` is not `async` (not returning a `Promise`), so the `await` call returns prematurely, at which point your test tries to assert something that hasn't occurred yet. To resolve this, just wrap the function body with a `Promise`:

```js
registerViaEmail() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (this.password.length > 0 && this.password === this.passwordReenter) {
      firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.emailAdress, this.password).then((result) => {
        //...
        resolve()
      }).catch((error) => {
        //...
        reject()
      });
    } else {
      //...
      reject()
    }
  })
},
```

2. The [script](https://github.com/mrbenhowl/mocking-firebase-initializeApp-and-firebase-auth-using-jest) you referred to is not intended to be used with Jest `__mocks__`. The script itself directly modifies the `firebase` object, replacing its methods/properties with mocks. To use the script, you just need to import it before importing the test module that uses `firebase`:

```js
import './firebase-mock' // <-- order important
import EmailSignupLogin from '@/components/EmailSignupLogin'
```

3. `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` does not return anything. It looks like it [originally returned the `Promise`](https://github.com/mrbenhowl/mocking-firebase-initializeApp-and-firebase-auth-using-jest/blame/master/README.md#L26), but you modified it with a `console.log`, and forgot to continue returning the `Promise`, which prevented this method from being `await`ed (same issue as #1). The solution there is to return the `Promise`:

```js
const createUserWithEmailAndPassword = jest.fn(() => {
  console.log('heeeeelllo')
  return /**/ Promise.resolve(/*...*/)
})
```

4. `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` is the method to be tested in `EmailSignupLogin`, but it's currently not mocked in your `auth` mock object. It's only mocked in the return of `initializeApp.auth`, but that's not what it being used in `EmailSignupLogin`. To resolve the issue, copy `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` to your `auth` mock object:

```js
jest.spyOn(firebase, 'auth').mockImplementation(() => ({
  onAuthStateChanged,
  currentUser: {
    displayName: 'testDisplayName',
    email: 'test@test.com',
    emailVerified: true,
  },
  getRedirectResult,
  sendPasswordResetEmail,
  createUserWithEmailAndPassword, //
}));
```

5. In your test setup, you mocked the store with a plain object, but it actually needs to be an instance of `Vuex.Store`:

```js
mount({
  //store: { /*...*/ },              //❌DON'T DO THIS
  store: new Vuex.Store({ /*...*/ }) //✅
})
```

[Github demo](https://github.com/tony19-sandbox/vue-firebase-mock-demo)